# Why aren't my placeholders working with an auto-fill script?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function getBooking() {
  if (sessionStorage.fname != undefined) {
    document.getElementById("confirm_fname").textContent = sessionStorage.fname;
    document.getElementById("confirm_lname").textContent = sessionStorage.lname;
    document.getElementById("confirm_email").textContent = sessionStorage.email;
    document.getElementById("confirm_gender").textContent = sessionStorage.gender;
    document.getElementById("confirm_phone").textContent = sessionStorage.phone;
    document.getElementById("confirm_start").textContent = sessionStorage.start;
    document.getElementById("confirm_streetname").textContent = sessionStorage.streetname;
    document.getElementById("confirm_suburb").textContent = sessionStorage.suburb;
    document.getElementById("confirm_state").textContent = sessionStorage.state;
    document.getElementById("confirm_postcode").textContent = sessionStorage.postcode;
    document.getElementById("confirm_skill").textContent = sessionStorage.skill;
    document.getElementById("confirm_other").textContent = sessionStorage.other;
    document.getElementById("confirm_otherbox").textContent = sessionStorage.otherbox;
    
    
    document.getElementById("a_fname").value = sessionStorage.fname;
    document.getElementById("a_lname").value = sessionStorage.lname;
    document.getElementById("a_email").value = sessionStorage.email;
    document.getElementById("a_gender").value = sessionStorage.gender;
    document.getElementById("a_phone").value = sessionStorage.phone;
    document.getElementById("a_start").value = sessionStorage.start;
    document.getElementById("a_streetname").value = sessionStorage.streetname;
    document.getElementById("a_suburb").value = sessionStorage.suburb;
    document.getElementById("a_state").value = sessionStorage.state;
    document.getElementById("a_postcode").value = sessionStorage.postcode;
    document.getElementById("a_skill").value = sessionStorage.skill;
    document.getElementById("a_other").value = sessionStorage.other;
    document.getElementById("a_otherbox").value = sessionStorage.otherbox;
  }
 }

function prefillcard()
{ 
  document.getElementById("fname").value =  sessionStorage.fname;
  document.getElementById("lname").value =  sessionStorage.lname;
  document.getElementById("email").value =  sessionStorage.email;
  document.getElementById("gender").value =  sessionStorage.gender;
  document.getElementById("phone").value =  sessionStorage.phone;
  document.getElementById("start").value =  sessionStorage.start;
  document.getElementById("streetname").value =  sessionStorage.streetname;
  document.getElementById("suburb").value =  sessionStorage.suburb;
  document.getElementById("state").value =  sessionStorage.state;
  document.getElementById("postcode").value =  sessionStorage.postcode;
  document.getElementById("skill").value =  sessionStorage.skill;
  document.getElementById("other").value =  sessionStorage.other;
  document.getElementById("otherbox").value =  sessionStorage.otherbox;
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", prefillcard);

function init() {
  var regForm = document.getElementById("regform");

  regForm.onsubmit = validate;
}
```

```html
    <section class="applything">
      <h2> Warning: you have 3 minutes to fill out the form before being redirected back to previous page </h2>
      <br>
      <h2>Job application:</h2>
      <br>
      <div class="containerr">
        <body>
        <form action="https://mercury.swin.edu.au/it000000/formtest.php" method="post" id="regform">
          <p>Job Reference Number: <span id="job1"></span> <span id="job2"></span> <span id="job3"></span>
          </p>
          <br>
          <br>
          <label for="fname">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name.." required="required" maxlength="25" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123) || (event.charCode==32)">
          <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name.." required="required" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123) || (event.charCode==32)">
          <label for="start">Date of birth:</label>
          <input type="date" id="start" required="required" name="date of birth" value="2021-10-04" />
          <br>
          <br>
          <label for="gender"> Select your gender</label>
          <br>
          <br>
          <select name="gender" id="gender" required="required">
            <option value="" selected>Please Select</option>
            <option value="male">Male</option>
            <option value="female">Female</option>
          </select>
          <br>
          <label for="streetname">Street Address</label>
          <input type="text" id="streetname" name="streetname" required="required" placeholder="Your street name..." maxlength="40" />
          <label for="suburb">Suburb/Town</label>
          <input type="text" id="suburb" name="suburb" required="required" placeholder="Your suburb/town..." maxlength="40">
          <label for="state">Choose a state:</label>
          <br>
          <select name="state" id="state" required="required">
            <option value="">Please Select</option>
            <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
            <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
            <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
            <option value="NT">NT</option>
            <option value="WA">WA</option>
            <option value="SA">SA</option>
            <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
            <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
          </select>
          <br>
          <br>
          <label for="postcode">Postcode</label>
          <input type="text" id="postcode" name="postcode" required="required" placeholder="Your postcode..." maxlength="4" minlength="4" pattern="^[0-9]{4}$">
          <label for="email">Email Address</label>
          <input type="text" id="email" name="emailadd" placeholder="Your email address.." required="required">
          <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
          <input type="text" id="phone" name="phonenumb" placeholder="e.g. 0451124561" minlength="8" maxlength="12" required="required">
          <br>
          <label>Skills</label>
          <br>
          <br>
          <input type="checkbox" id="skill" name="skill1" value="Javascript">
          <label for="skill1"> Extensive knowledge of Javascript</label>
          <br>
          <br>
          <input type="checkbox" id="skill" name="skill2" value="Python">
          <label for="skill2"> Extensive knowledge of Python</label>
          <br>
          <br>
          <input type="checkbox" id="skill" name="skill3" value="Networking">
          <label for="skill3"> Extensive knowledge of Networking</label>
          <br>
          <br>
          <input type="checkbox" id="skill" name="skill4" value="Data Storage">
          <label for="skill4"> Extensive knowledge of Data storage fundamentals</label>
          <br>
          <br>
          <input type="checkbox" id="skill" name="skill5" value="Security Foundations">
          <label for="skill5"> Extensive knowledge of Security foundations</label>
          <br>
          <br>
          <input type="checkbox" id="skill" name="skill6" value="AWS Service Selection">
          <label for="skill6"> Extensive knowledge of AWS service selection</label>
          <br>
          <br>
          <input type="checkbox" id="skill" name="skill7" value="Teamwork">
          <label for="skill7"> Ability to work in a team</label>
          <br>
          <br>
          <input type="checkbox" id="skill" name="skill8" value="5+ Years">
          <label for="skill8"> 5+ years experience</label>
          <br>
          <br>
          <input type="checkbox" id="skill" name="skill9" value="10+ Years">
          <label for="skill9"> 10+ years experience</label>
          <br>
          <br>
          <input type="checkbox" id="skill" name="skill10" value="20+ Years">
          <label for="skill10"> 20+ years experience</label>
          <br>
          <br>
          <input type="checkbox" id="other" name="other" value="other" onclick="otherCheckBox()" />
          <label for="other"> I have other skills. Please list other skills below.</label>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
          <textarea id="otherbox" name="other skill" placeholder="textarea" style="height:200px"></textarea>
          <input type="submit" value="Apply">
          <br>
          <br>
          <input type="reset" id="cancelpurchase" value="Cancel Application"></input>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          document.getElementById("job1").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("jobreference1");
          document.getElementById("job2").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("jobreference2");
          document.getElementById("job3").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("jobreference3");
        </script>
      </body>
      </div>
    </section>
    <div class="footer">
      <div class="footer-content"></div>
      <div class="footer-bottom"></div> &copy; swintech.com | Designed by Bilal El-leissy
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've set up a function that auto-fills the form if the user had previously submitted it in the same browser session. The only problem is that, before submitting it for the first time, a text fills every input reading "undefined" despite me adding placeholders in HTML. How do I make it so that the "undefined" goes away?

Comment: On the `prefillcard` function you should also set an `if (sessionStorage.fname != undefined)` statement

Comment: @AgamemnonKatradis Thank you so much. This worked. Can't believe I didn't see it earlier.

Comment: @AgamemnonKatradis Why did you not add this as an answer?

Comment: I had this as a suggestion in my mind, did not have time to actually test this